# SpringBoot with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, junit

I want to someone to help me with this , i am new to spring boot ,
TO DO : write methods in class Test main ,
Run with JUNIT without JSP
Entity : Formation : id, titre, price(decimal), durée(integer) et begin_at(date)

Comment: is it you want to convert your JSP Servlet application to REST Spring Boot?

Comment: Could you describe it a little bit more clear? Do you just want to run tests? Or connect with a mysql db?